# Why are large DBs usually implemented as shards full of replicas instead of replicas full of shards?

Tags: database, replication, sharding

I have ssearched the internet for information on replication and sharding and found that when both are used together, they almost always consider the following scenario:

A query from an application server is received. A routing software of some kind routes to a shard. That shard consults some appropriate replica based on the query and returns the result.

I'm curious whether this scenario is ever implemented:

A query from an application server is received. The routing software (such as mongo-S in mongoDB) chooses one of several replicas. Within that replica are shards of the different db tables. It chooses an appropriate one and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach will never fit with the MongoDB Architecture because:

- In a sharded cluster first, if the query key is a shard key. It needs to identify the exact shard in which the particular data will be. After that, it will search for the primary replica of that shard to get the data.
- Now let us assume if mongo first searches for the replica,  Then the whole concept of shards will be wasted :
      - As all the queries will land up to one replica node. And the other brokers will remain unutilised.

Comment: 1. That doesn't make sense to me. In the case of a bunch of replicas which contains shards, then every replica has the full set of data needed to answer any query. After the query has been sent to a replica, then the replica can choose the appropriate shard within that replica based on the shard key, and return the data. I am assuming that replicas or replica sets can consist of multiple machines. Am I making sense? Could you explain a little further?